# UIDevice set orientation doesn't change view bounds

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, rotation

I call:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft]
                                    forKey:@"orientation"];
```

And then I log out:

```
NSLog(@" = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
```

And I get:

```
2015-04-06 11:04:13.02 [1032:262526]  = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
```

This is on an iPhone 6. How come the `bounds` didn't change?

### EDIT

So I saw in another answer that `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` gives the proper dimensions after setting rotation programmatically using `setValue:forKey`.

However, how come the `view` still has the portrait frame? Is this a delayed response? Do I have to rotate the view myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change interface orientation then you should look towards this callbacks

```
 interfaceOrientation  property
– shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
+ attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation
– rotatingHeaderView
– rotatingFooterView
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

and I will suggest you to look towards this method too.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceO‌​rientation
```

Please refer this [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

adject your code inside this 
`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceO‌​rientation
if UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft{//code} else if UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight{//code}`